# Which color space to use in camera while shooting video? RGB or YCbCr?

Tags: video, camera, color, colorspace, shooting

I want to shoot videos for my blog. Nature, landscapes, fitness. Which color space to use in camera while shooting video? RGB or YCbCr?

Answer (score 1):

The question is impossible to answer in a general way.

If a camera offers to record in RGB, it is likely using a completely different codec that could be better or worse.  Very few cameras will actually record video in RGB, so if you see the option in a menu, it may be referring to something very particular about the color handling of video on that specific model of camera.

What camera? And what is the exact context of the option?

Comment: Thank you, wrosecrans. I have no camera. I want to choose and buy. Wich color space and wich codec camera should have?

Comment: That just isn't the right question to ask about a camera.  Read some camera reviews.  If a camera is heavy, has crappy picture quality, low resolution, bad battery life, takes blurry pictures, and the UI is hard to use, it doesn't matter if it theoretically does some internal image processing step in a scientifically superior color space.